# cross DBs programmatic tables creation/alter?

Tags: java, sql

I'm starting some new code aiming Mysql and Oracle, plus H2 for in memory testing. This code has then to be deployed on our customer's sites.

Since it'll evolve over time, I'm planning to use [flywaydb.org java migration](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/java.html), however I haven't found any java/jvm library allowing me to  declare/alter tables and query/insert them through typesafe code for the required DBs.

Any hint of a library doing so?

My investigation so far:

- Hibernate doesn't support migration & programmatic creation/alter of
  table (just startup time create/update options, which are way less
  powerful)
- querydsl doesn't support table creation/alter
- typesafe's slick required paid support for oracle

I would have to have to fallback to plain old SQL written 3 times...

best

Comment: I don't think these kinds of database creation tasks should be done by a Java runtime.  They should be part of the setup for each client, done using appropriate scripts for each database.  Perhaps unfortunate, but it's the price of having to support multiple relational databases.

Comment: Well, we use flywaydb already with migrations files per db. It's time consuming and error prone... Hence my quest, err, question ;)

Comment: Look for a way to write the sql once and use it three times.

Comment: Check out Liquibase instead of Flyway. Its XML format is as DBMS independent as possible. (Although I think using a different DBMS for testing than in production is a *very* bad idea)

Comment: Actually I plan on writing the sql through jOOQ: cross db, typesafe, write once run on many DB. All good IMHO. The demo is already working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out http://www.jooq.org/ does it, jooq's motto being to provide all SQL functionalities in Java through a DSL and in a cross database way. Really sweet :)